# PostGIS to Oracle Query Conversion

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, postgis, oracle-spatial

I have tried my hardest to convert this query and I am just failing. Some Oracle expert assistance would be awesome. Thank you :)

```
select * from (
    select 
        st_setsrid(st_makepoint(ee.startLng, ee.starLat), 4326) as geomstart,
        st_setsrid(st_makepoint(ee.endLng, ee.endLat), 4326) as geomend
    from events ee
) e
inner join (
    select 
        (st_dump(st_linemerge(st_locatebetween(geom,6.1199,59.5117)))).geom
        , route 
        from  (
            select 
                st_makeline(
                    st_setsrid(
                        st_makepointm(rp.lng,rp.lat,rp.m)
                        ,4326
                    ) 
                    order by rp.m 
                ) as geom
                , max(lr.route) as route
                , max(lr.id) as routeid
            from rpoints rp 
            inner join routes lr 
            on lr.id = rp.route_id 
            where lr.id = 9
        ) m
) l
on st_dwithin(e.geomstart,l.geom, 0.00001) or ST_DWITHIN(e.geomend, l.geom, 0.00001)
```

The query is here.

Comment: You need to help us a bit by explaining what this tries to accomplish. Also things like how do those tables look like (`routes`, `rpoints`). This looks like an LRS problem you want to solve - like some dynamic segmentation ?

Comment: Albert, thanks for replying.I will tell you what I can. the data has already been ETL into oracle (have no control of this). In oracle there is a table that has a geometry field. This field contains both points and lines. As for the postgres side. the points are exactly that points. The routes is just a table for the points to link to (for names). Route 1 -> links to points the points are making up the line by the miles (miles is the measurement between each point). So there is a point that starts at 0 miles and the miles have an aggregate distance. the location tables have been transfererd

Comment: The goal is that someone selects a start and end point (from a route) we then can give them events that happened within that segment of line on the route (the larger line). In this case "6.1199,59.5117" represents start and end (miles) on the line. Please keep in mind I am very new to LRS in the GIS spatial world. I am normally just used to points and bounds and using a leaflet or o2layers library to assist in analysis.